# Как правильно вывести данные из разных таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql

Имеются три таблицы из которых нужно вывести данные. Все нужно засунуть в массив и потом вывести. Нужно проверить если подсчет в запросе равен 0 то вевести текст допусти не заказов.

```
class Statistics {
        public $connection = null;
        public $result = array();

        public function __construct() {
            $this->connection = new mysqli('localhost','root','','mydb');
            $this->connection->set_charset('utf8');
            $this->get_statistics();
        }

        public function get_statistics () {
            if(!$this->connection->connect_errno) {
                /* Заказ */
                $order_query = $this->connection->query("SELECT count(*) FROM orders");
                if($order_query->num_rows != 0) {
                    $order_result = $order_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
                    if($order_result[0] != 0) {
                        $this->result[0] = $order_result[0];
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->result[0] = 'Нет заказов';
                    }
                }
                /* /Заказ */
                /* Отзывы */
                $review_query = $this->connection->query("SELECT count(*) FROM reviews");
                if($review_query->num_rows > 0) {
                    $review_result = $review_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
                    if($review_result[0] != 0) {
                        $this->result[1] = $review_result[0];
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->result[1] = 'Нет отзывов';
                    }
                }
                /* /Отзывы */
                /* Скидка */
                $discount_query = $this->connection->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users");
                if($discount_query->num_rows != 0) {
                    $discount_result = $discount_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
                    if($discount_result[0] != 0) {
                        $this->result[2] = $discount_result[0];
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->result[2] = 'Нет желающих получить скидку';
                    }
                }
                /* /Скидка */
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

зачем вам делать $this->connection->query("SELECT count(*) FROM discount"); кода можно сделать

```
$arr = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
if($arr != null && count($arr) > 0)
{
   echo 'Заказы есть!';
}
else echo 'Заказов нет!';
```

Answer (score 0):

я в своем приложение делаю подсчет следуюшим образом:

```
$zapros=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($zapros);
if ($data[0]==0) { echo 'Заказов нет!'; } else {  }
```